# Android Studio debugger going to class file instead of source code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I am working on android app and using Cipher class to do some processing. Facing some problems in this, so want to stop the execution and put breakpoints in Cipher class.

The problem is, I've the source code downloaded for the Cipher class (from android sdk, v27) and am putting breakpoints there. The debugger stops at the specified method but it picks the Cipher class file that's present on my system's jdk.

Below screenshots will explain it clearly:

[image: The source file that I want]

[image: The class file that debugger picks up]

Comment: I faced the similar issue. I imported the wrong class. You might want to check your imports.

Comment: you can see a lock just under java icon of class name. That means this specific class is read only. I believe you either have to import those files in your project like fork them or check your imports .

Comment: add **app.gradle** where you added the dependency for more detailed explanation @yashasvi